# Converting a fluent builder to run in parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I currently have a fluent builder, .e.g

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject.Builder()
    .field1(someWebService.getSomeValue())
    .field2(someOtherService.getSomething())
    .field3(anotherService.youGetThePicture())
    // etc x 10
    .createSomeObject()
```

I'd like to elegantly convert this to run in parallel, so the three service calls can run at the same time. Is this possible? I'm using Java 8 so streams are an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well **just for reference** what you want to do could be done like this

```
    SomeObject.Builder someObject = new SomeObject.Builder();
    CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> someObject.field1(someWebService.getSomeValue());
    CompletableFuture cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> someObject.field2(someOtherService.getSomething());
    ...
    SomeObject res = CompletableFuture.allOf(cf1, cf2, ...).get().createSomeObject();
```

**But I would strongly advice you to instead** call the services asynchronously, collect the responses and then build your object synchronously.

If you want to do it using streams you should add all the lambdas (service calls) into a collection and then use `serviceCalls.stream().parallel().forEach(Consumer::accept);`
Thats not good either though